# How do I deploy to an Azure Web App on Linux using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) have a link to Deployments > Azure Web App on Windows but no link to Azure Web App on Linux.

[Update]

Here is my latest attempt
[image: Deploy]

It is not possible to data enter the app service name.

[Update]

It turns out that the order of filling things in matters.
Once I filled in the settings for the pipeline task then I could enter data in the Azure App Service Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Azure App Service Deploy](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/549991bd1014136505a6266f9c042214bf12ba49/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4) task supports Web App on Linux app service type, so you can directly deploy Azure Web App on Linux through this task. See [Deploy: Azure App Service Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=vsts) for details.

> The Azure App Service Deploy task is used to deploy to a range of App
>   Services on Azure. The task works on cross-platform agents running
>   Windows, Linux, or Mac.

Reference this similar thread : [VSTS Deploy to Azure WebApp For Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525048/vsts-deploy-to-azure-webapp-for-linux)

And you can also reference this article for the deployment: [Docker Deployment to Azure App Service (Linux) using VSTS](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/docker/)

[image]